# WPF Validation: How to validate the whole page

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I am using the following articles to validate inputs from the user:

http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/06/24/wpf-textbox-validation.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/07/28/wpf-textbox-validation-2.aspx

I have a window with 100+ textbox, and I need to check with all textboxes are valid.

Imagine the following situation -> User has inputted an invalid value:

- 1) The validation rule will verify the error and display an error
  message (Good!)
- 2) The viewmodel will not know that the value has
  been updated (with a invalid string). It will remain with its old
  value.
- 3) Thus, any attempt to bind a "save" button enabled to an `IsValid`
  property will fail. (as described in article 2) (Bad!)

So, my question is: How can I validate the whole page in the view model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very good article [here](http://thejoyofcode.com/silverlight_validation_and_viewmodel.aspx) dealing with exactly this problem -- I used this approach, and it works nicely.

The basic idea is to use an attached property -- call it "ValidationScope.Errors" -- to bind the view's validation scope to a property in your view-model.

Here's the code, quoted from the linked article:

```
public class ValidationScope
{
    public static IList GetErrors(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IList)obj.GetValue(ErrorsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetErrors(DependencyObject obj, IList value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ErrorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Errors", typeof(IList), typeof(ValidationScope), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, ErrorsChanged));

    public static void ErrorsChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)obj;
        element.BindingValidationError += delegate(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
                {
                    GetErrors(obj).Add(e.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    GetErrors(obj).Remove(e.Error);
                }
            };
    }
}
```

You can see this attached dependency property works by listening to the framework's `BindingValidationError` event, and adding/removing errors to the view-model target you specify.  To use this in your code, simply bind the dependency property `ValidationScope.Errors` to a target property in your view model:

```
<my:SomeUserControl my:ValidationScope.Errors="{Binding MyViewModel.Errors}" />
```

Now your view-model contains a property "Errors" that you can use to check whether the view is actually valid or not.

Comment: very good! I haven´t tested it yet, but it seems exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: the example provided is for silverlight. Some features will not work

Comment: @guilhermecgs ah ... sorry about that.

Comment: I solved the problem using Validation.Error event and a counter